# Why do we use silicon in the crystal direction [1 0 0]?

Tags: mosfet, bjt, physics, silicon

In MOSFET, we use silicon in crystal direction [1 0 0] , while we use direction [1 1 1]  in BJT. What is the reason? I expect the opposite, because we see more atoms on the surface in the direction [1 1 1] and so diffusion of atoms is very harder. Also, in BJT, we need a deeper diffusion.

**UPDATE**

crystal directions are specified by [miller index](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index).

Comment: You might need to post a picture that explains your co-ordinate system (unfathomable at the moment).

Comment: Probably referring to the [Miller index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_index).

Comment: There's a lot of technology (aka know-how) goes in to what crystal direction to use for any given semiconductor application. A one-property thing like 'more atoms' sounds unlikely to capture the pros and cons of carrier mobility, any diffusion anisotropy, etc etc. The physics site might suit this question better.

Comment: Physics site is a general forum. This question is specific to electronic engineering.

Comment: I guess the [001] is the standard choice due to the easier dicing. So one can check what other advantages 111 wafers have. A very quick search suggested that oxide growth was faster on 111.

Comment: Relevant link: https://www.universitywafer.com/silicon-orientation.html